# Bash script Find and Sort oldest first on two different types of files

Tags: shell, loops, sorting, filter, find

In my bash script I am using the find to filter two types of files, let's **students.txt** and **teachers.txt**.

The order matters oldest comes first and meanwhile first **students1 and then teachers1**, **students2 and then teachers2**, **studentsN and then teachersN**.

The following script sorts the oldest first and the most recent lasts. **However, it does not** meanwhile consider first students1 and then teachers1, students2 and then teachers2, studentsN and then teachersN. What do you suggest?

```
#!/bin/bash

THE_PATH="THE_PATH"

while IFS='' read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS='' read -r -d '' filename
do
  echo "processing file \"$filename\""
done < <(find "$THE_PATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f \( -iname "*students*.txt" -o -iname "*teachers*.txt" \) -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn)
```

**The files that I have:**

```
Modified Time                   File Name
oct 22 2019                     student1010.txt
oct 22 2019                     teacher2000.txt
oct 21 2019                     teacher1000.txt
oct 15 2019                     teacher3000.txt
oct 15 2019                     student3030.txt
oct 20 2019                     student4040.txt
```

**The output that I want:**

```
Modified Time                   File Name
oct 15 2019                     student3030.txt
oct 15 2019                     teacher3000.txt
oct 20 2019                     student4040.txt
oct 21 2019                     teacher1000.txt
oct 22 2019                     student1010.txt
oct 22 2019                     teacher2000.txt
```

I have the following solutions in mind **BUT** looking forward if it is achievable with above example:

1. Create an array using the find command as process substitution to the loop for the student.txt files;
2. Create another array using the find command as process substitution to the loop for the teacher.txt files;
3. Finally create another array out of the above created two arrays while reading single element from each at a time.

Comment: You question is not clear. Consider posting sample input files (students.txt, teachers.txt - at least first line), and desired output

Comment: @dash-o I added more details to the question.

Comment: I think it's still not clear why can you just 'sort' the find output ?

Comment: @dash-o because I need to process from the oldest to the most recent of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To process the oldest to most recent files such as (student1 and then teacher1; student2 and then teacher2, studentN and then teacherN), I implemented the following logic.

Please the comments in the code for further clarification:

```
#!/bin/bash

THE_PATH="THE_PATH"

# Create an array of all the student files
STUDENT_files=()
while IFS='' read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
    STUDENT_files+=("$file")
done < <(find "$THE_PATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*student*.txt" -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn)

# Create an array of all the teacher files
TEACHER_files=()
while IFS='' read -r -d ' ' mtime && IFS='' read -r -d '' file
do
    TEACHER_files+=("$file")
done < <(find "$THE_PATH" -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*teacher*.txt" -printf '%T@ %p\0' | sort -zn)

# Merge STUDENT and TEACHER such as (STUDENT1 and then TEACHER1; and STUDENT2 and then TEACHER2, ...)
All_files=()
i=0
j=0
k=0

# Traverse both array
total_STUDENT="${#STUDENT_files[@]}"
total_TEACHER="${#TEACHER_files[@]}"
while [ $i -lt $total_STUDENT -a $j -lt $total_TEACHER ] 
do
    All_files[$((k++))]="${STUDENT_files[$((i++))]}"
    All_files[$((k++))]="${TEACHER_files[$((j++))]}"
done

# Store remaining STUDENT files
while [ $i -lt $total_STUDENT ]
do
    All_files[$((k++))]="${STUDENT_files[$((i++))]}"
done

# Store remaining TEACHER files
while [ $j -lt $total_TEACHER ]
do
    All_files[$((k++))]="${TEACHER_files[$((j++))]}"
done

# Process the files in correct order
for file in "${All_files[@]}"
do
    echo "$file"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

There was already an accepted answer, but I would like to propose this one: An unique (sorted) table containing teachers and students, and 2 cursors to traverse it.

I also removed the NULL terminated stuff, I am not sure what it was for: Maybe some fancy filenames? With given example, no need for that for sure.

```
#!/bin/bash

THE_PATH="/tmp"

files=()
cd $THE_PATH

while read mtime filename; do
    files+=($filename)
done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -regex ".*\(teac\|stud\).*" -printf '%T@ %f\n' |\
             sort -n)

max=${#files[@]}

for ((student=0, teacher=0; student < max && teacher < max; student++, teacher++)); do
    # find next student and next teacher
    while (( student < max )) && [[ ! ${files[$student]} =~ ^student ]] ; do
        (( student++ ))
    done
    (( student == max )) && break

    while (( teacher < max )) && [[ ! ${files[$teacher]} =~ ^teacher ]] ; do
        (( teacher++ ))
    done
    (( teacher == max )) && break

    printf "%s\n%s\n" ${files[$student]} ${files[$teacher]}
done
```